# CAS Authentication Integration with Websphere portal

Tags: websphere, single-sign-on, cas, portal, websphere-portal

I have been trying to use the CAS Authentication for a Websphere Portal 8.0.1 application. Followed a few links :

https://wiki.jasig.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=19314
https://portalplus.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/configure-websphere-portal-with-cas-sso/

This help was mainly in pursuit of finding a ready-made Trust Association Interceptor (TAI) and a possible login modules if needed.

But looks like Portal CASsification is not a well known territory. I did all the configurations , but looks like TAI is not calling CAS serviceValidation URL, so even when I am redirected to portal application , the session is not authenticated, So I see blank portlets.

So I am stuck at a few points :

1. Apart from Yale provided TAI , is there a open/closed sourced library for CASifying Websphere portal application.
2. Do we need to provide CAS filters in wps.ear web.xml or in the web.xml for the portal application war.? Or should be taken care by the TAI interceptor ?

Websphere portal is very rigid to the open source auth libraries!!

Appreciate any help!!

Comment: have you checked the debug messages and the WebSphere TAI traces if the TAI is called and takes responsibility for the request. And is the Portal url you use for redirection the protected or unprotected (portal = unprotected myportal = protected)